# Как сделать вывод одной таблицы, основываясь на вывод другой?

Tags: sql, postgresql, сортировка, таблицы

Мне нужно сделать вывод из таблицы в том порядке, в котором выбрал user

```
1) Сортировка по дате и времени.
2) Сортировка по популярности
3) Сортировать по количеству
4) Сортировать по количеству отзывов
5) Сортировать по цене
```

Всего я разобрался с 3 задачами: 1, 3 и 5. Для решения других 2 задач, нужно понять строение таблиц.

```
subject
+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| id_subject  |                                  info                                   | user_id |
+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| 1::serial8  | {"product": ..., "title": ..., "description": ..., "price": ...}::json  | 52::int |
| 2::serial8  | {"product": ..., "title": ..., "description": ..., "price": ...}::json  | 37::int |
  ...

200 row(s)
```

```
review
+---------+--------------+-------------+---------+
| rating  |   review     | id_subject  | user_id |
+---------+--------------+-------------+---------+
| 1       | '...'::text  |          2  |     367 |
| 2       | null         |          2  |      94 |
| null    | '...'::text  |          2  |      27 |
| 5       | '...'::text  |          1  |     896 |
  ...
1000 row(s)
```

Что особенного для второго варианта "Сортировка по популярности", это то, что sql запрос

`SELECT sum(rating) / count(*) FROM review WHERE review notnull GROUP BY id_subject;` сделает вывод как положено, но при этом не так как нужно мне.

А вот запрос `SELECT info::json->>'title', info::json->>'price' FROM subject ORDER BY ( SELECT sum(rating) / count(*) FROM review WHERE review notnull GROUP BY id_subject ) ASC;`

выведет ошибку `ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

Я понял, это все потому что, где либо `rating is null` или возможно вообще не существует запись с данным `subject_id`. Но мне кажется, вместо этой ошибки postgres могла бы вывести значения равные нулю.

Аналогично для варианта "Сортировка по количеству отзывов".
Я сразу покажу свой запрос который выведет ту же ошибку, что и ранее.
`SELECT id_subject, info::json->>'product', info::json->>'price' FROM subject ORDER BY (SELECT count(*) FROM review WHERE review notnull GROUP BY id_subject) ASC;`

Comment: У меня были мысли написать свою функцию для решения вопроса, но проблема в том что я понятий не имею как это делать. Лимит тоже не помог. Больше идей нет.

Comment: Если будут интересующиеся, то решение [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1314684/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8f-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)