# Как сделать правильное взаимодействие между двумя sql запросами?

Tags: sql, postgresql, сортировка, table

Этот вопрос является отсылкой к моему [прежнему вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1314533/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9).
Вот к чему я пришел:

```
SELECT id_subject, info::json->>'price' 
FROM subject 
WHERE id_subject IN (SELECT id_subject 
                     FROM review 
                     GROUP BY id_subject) 
ORDER BY ( SELECT count(review) as ii 
           FROM review 
           WHERE review notnull 
           GROUP BY id_subject 
           ORDER BY ii ASC ) DESC;
```

Этот запрос выдает ошибку

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Но если изменить запрос на

```
SELECT id_subject, info::json->>'price' 
FROM subject 
WHERE id_subject IN (SELECT id_subject 
                     FROM review 
                     GROUP BY id_subject);
```

консоль сделает вывод

| id_subject | ?column? |
| --- | --- |
| 187 | 246.32 |
| 191 | 13.63 |
| 212 | 715.44 |
| 302 | 743.3 |
| 325 | 438.0 |
| 320 | 43.5 |
| 336 | 742.7 |
| 345 | 349.1 |
| 338 | 102.5 |
| 269 | 382.44 |
| 374 | 483.2 |
| 197 | 955.4 |
| 278 | 273.62 |
| 280 | 826.26 |
| 199 | 456.88 |

В общем по моим выводам, это не правильное взаимодействие запросов:

```
SELECT id_subject, info::json->>'price' 
FROM subject 
WHERE id_subject IN (SELECT id_subject 
                     FROM review 
                     GROUP BY id_subject)
```

c

```
SELECT count(review) as ii 
FROM review 
WHERE review notnull 
GROUP BY id_subject 
ORDER BY ii ASC
```

Comment: А с чего Вы решили, что два подзапроса в первом запросе имеют хоть что-то общее? они независимы.

Comment: Я нашел такой вариант решения `SELECT subject.id_subject, subject.info::json->>'price' FROM subject LEFT JOIN review ON subject.id_subject = review.id_subject WHERE review.rating notnull ORDER BY ( SELECT sum(rating) / count(rating) FROM review WHERE rating notnull) ASC;`, но почему то вывод происходит совершенно не правильно https://pastebin.com/Pw8H3AZH

Comment: Такой вариант заведомо неверен. Опять - `review` в запросе и подзапросе есть две абсолютно независимые копии таблицы, считай вообще разные таблицы, просто почему-то называются одинаково.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, требуется

```
SELECT subject.id_subject, subject.info::json->>'price' 
FROM subject 
JOIN ( SELECT id_subject, COUNT(review) cnt
       FROM review 
       GROUP BY id_subject ) subquery USING (id_subject)
ORDER BY subquery.cnt DESC
```

Comment: Появлялась ошибка в `SUM(...)`, замениил на `count()`

Comment: @v1nc3nt_0'ne1ll Пардон, забыл, что Постгресс. Поправил.

Comment: Короче говоря, я пришел к решению благодаря этому ответу. Я до сих пор не понял что значит `cnt`, `subquery` и `subquery.cnt`. Видиимо я слишком новичок. Я в свой запросе эти моменты изменил на `AS`. Мне так привычнее. В общем, в моем имправлении, допонительно сортируют по title. Я считаю это эстетично. А сам запрос вот `SELECT subject.id_subject, subject.info::json->>\'price\', subject.info->>\'title\' as jj, full_product FROM subject JOIN ( SELECT review.id_subject, count(review.review IS NOT NULL) as ii FROM review GROUP BY id_subject ) dd USING (id_subject) ORDER BY ii DESC, jj ASC;`.